# some emails do not send because wrong IP of destination mailserver

Tags: postfix, reverse-dns

in my postfix log files I found a strange thing.
some domains resolve always to the same one IP address, but not every time. Just sometimes.

```
Oct 28 14:51:46 maxi postfix/smtp[4057]: 5628514640F0: to=<Gxxx_Vxxx@LGI.DE>, relay=none, delay=88712, delays=88711/0.02/0.25/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to dmzsrv01.LGI.DE[192.64.147.142]:25: Connection refused)
Oct 28 16:21:32 maxi postfix/smtp[7195]: 555AF14634D2: to=<axxx.bxxx@ecoma-dichtungen.de>, relay=none, delay=176789, delays=176789/0.04/0.23/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.ecoma-dichtungen.de[192.64.147.142]:25: Connection refused)
Oct 28 16:21:32 maxi postfix/smtp[7196]: 3B23B146410A: to=<Jxxx.Fxxx@hgmtk.de>, relay=none, delay=547, delays=547/0.04/0.23/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.hgmtk.de[192.64.147.142]:25: Connection refused)
```

I just changed the localpart in the emails for privacy reasons, 
but as you can see all mail servers seem to be 192.64.147.142
Always the same IP 192.64.147.142

- dmzsrv01.LGI.DE should be 91.103.240.22
- mail.ecoma-dichtungen.de should be 213.174.32.95
- mail.hgmtk.de should be 188.174.253.114

Funny is that 192.64.147.142 belongs to VOODOO

```
NetRange:       192.64.144.0 - 192.64.151.255
CIDR:           192.64.144.0/21
NetName:        VOODOO-1
NetHandle:      NET-192-64-144-0-1
```

But this is not default, most servers are resolved right and email transport works good.

Has someone seen this behavior ?

Comment: What does your email server use for DNS?

Comment: I took a look into resolv.conf and there where 2 name servers who resolve any dig into the same IP address ( nameserver 23.27.48.58 nameserver 166.88.18.58 )

Answer (score 3):

Thank to the hint of joeqwerty I checked resolv.conf and there where 2 nameservers who seem to resolve any domain to the same IP address 192.64.147.142

besides the 2 name servers of my provider

```
nameserver 85.25.128.10
nameserver 85.25.255.10
```

where 2 other

```
nameserver 23.27.48.58
nameserver 166.88.18.58
```

I remembered there was a nameserver problem at my provider some time ago and I used the one from zoneedit in that time. 
But this name servers seem not to be ok. They do not resolve to zoneedit.

anyway thank you for your help joeqwerty

Comment: Glad to help...